# Returning specific DIV via specific TAG - PHP XPATH

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm interested in finding a particular div that contains in a particular tag.

**For exmaple:**

```
<div id="1">
<h1>abc</h1>
<div>asd</div>
<div>qwer</div>
</div>
```

if i choose H1 as tag so i will get back the div with id=1.

**My code:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
@$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[contains(text(),'<h1')]");
```

Comment: Is it always going to be a `div` or it might be arbitrary element?

Comment: @Rarst always be a div. the only thing that change is the TAG name.. like here is H1